# Push Notifications not working on RN0.62.2

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, push-notification, react-native-push-notification

In JS, using firebase.messaging().getToken();, I'm able to successfully get an FCM token.

I'm going into our project in Firebase and sending a test notification to this device.

The notification does not appear on my device.

So:

1.I'm able to generate an FCM token and correctly access it
2.No errors in Android Studio or during the build
3.No errors in my JS console
4.I'm not able to RECEIVE the push notification. Nothing happens. I've tried looking in the logs in android studio, but I'm not seeing anything (and the logs seem to stop running when my app is closed/in the background)

Comment: Did you complete the steps described here https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client?

Comment: Also I think that your problem is that notification messages are handled differently dependent on your app state. Here is the documentation fragment: "...Notification messages are delivered to the notification tray when the app is in the background. For apps in the foreground, messages are handled by a callback function...". So, when your app is in the background state, you should see notification tray message, but if app state is foreground, you should handle message in your FirebaseMessagingService implementation's onMessageReceived method.